# Python __hash__ performance for bulky data

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tech stack:

- Python 3.8

When this function (to re-structure data in acceptable format) is executed for

- few 100s of timestamps works efficiently (0.022 s)
- bulk in order of 100,000+ it takes lot of time (~40 seconds)

where length of grouped values is 250+.

```
def re_struct_data(all_timestamps: List, grouped_values: Dict[String, Dict[Integer, Integer]]):
    tm_count = len(all_timestamps)

    start_tm = 1607494871
    get_tms = lambda: [None] * tm_count
    data_matrix = {'runTime': get_tms()}

    for i_idx, tm in enumerate(all_timestamps):

        data_matrix['runTime'][i_idx] = float(tm) - start_tm
        for cnl_nm in grouped_values:
            if cnl_nm not in data_matrix:
                data_matrix[cnl_nm] = get_tms()

            value_dict = grouped_values[cnl_nm]
            if tm in value_dict:
                data_matrix[cnl_nm][i_idx] = value_dict[tm]
    return data_matrix
```

When I did code profiling for the same, got to know quite a handsome amount of time goes into hashing for the presence/ absence of `cnl_nm` in `data_matrix`.

I tried switching to

- setdefault() -> (as it does the same under the hood)
- Using `.items()` -> (tuple conversion + unpacking)

But it took more time.

ANy suggestions to improve the same?

Comment: Use a `defaultdict(get_tms)` instead of a dict, and keep the item around so you don't have to reindex into it. Incidentally 22ms for 100s items and 40s  for 100ks is the same efficiency, if your process is linear (here it's O(m*n) but it's unclear whether n is also increasing) it's unsurprising that multiplying the number of items by 1000 would increase the processing time by 1000 as well...

Comment: Incidentally you could iterate on `grouped_values.items()` to also avoid reindexing into it. And use `value_dict.get(tm)`, also in order to avoid doubly indexing into it. That should being down the number of indexing / hashing operations to 3 per loop (one being a list indexing) rather than the current worst-case of 7.

Comment: @Masklinn I tried using `.items()`. Converting into tuples and unpacking adds to the response time.

Will try defaultdict and update.